# El significado de "ir de largo"

Tags: significado

Según este [enlace](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ir-de-largo.164293/), "ir de largo" que se encuentra en la siguiente oración puede significar "pasar de largo". ¿Podría alguien confirmar que así es el caso? (Encontré este [enlace](https://mobile-dictionary.reverso.net/es/espanol-definiciones/ir+de+largo) que dice que "ir de largo" es "ir para largo", pero no sé ...)
Muchas gracias.

> Por eso no me puedo **ir de largo**, y ni me voy a ir tampoco.

Comment: Para mí la expresión "ir de largo" hace referencia a llevar puesto un vestido largo, que tape hasta los tobillos. Sin embargo no parece que encaje en el contexto de la frase. Tal vez convendría ampliar el contexto: exponer las frases anteriores y posteriores, comentar si la frase la dice un hombre o una mujer, en qué país transcurre la acción, etc.

Comment: Tu segundo enlace no se refiere a "ir de largo" sino a "ir para largo", el buscador ha mostrado la expresión más parecida, pero eso no significa que estén semánticamente relacionadas. Me sumo a la petición de Charlie, ¿cuál es el contexto de esa frase? ¿de donde sale?

Comment: En Colombia no usamos "irse de largo" pero entendemos que países vecinos la usan como "seguirse" o "pasarse del objetivo". Sin embargo si usamos mucho "ir para largo" o mejor "ir pa' largo" que es cuando se presiente que una situación va a durar mucho más de lo esperado. ej. **esta pandemia va pa' largo**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo con [esta fuente](http://xn--diccionariovariantesespaol-4rc.org/glosario/l/largo), "irse de largo" sería equivalente a "seguir de largo" (en el sentido de "seguir adelante"). Su uso parece restringido a ciertos países de Latinoamérica (en Argentina no se usa):

> seguir (/irse) de largo. loc.
>
> Seguir adelante.
>
> Col. *La camioneta sigue de largo, por detrás del chalet.* Ungar, Tres
>   34/3871.
>
> Per. *El ochenta por ciento de las cosas que he podido averiguar
>   llegaron así, en estas reuniones improvisadas que podían irse de largo
>   y terminar a varios kilómetros de Lima.* Trelles, Bioy 1493/3761.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aplicaciones !